# How do I change an image source from a different namespace?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces

I'm fairly new to C# so please pardon what may seem like a newb issue: I'm currently having trouble figuring out how to change an image on MainWindow from a different namespace.  Here's a simplified version of the issue I'm having:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="imageToChange" Source="images/01.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" />
</Grid>
```

ChangeImage.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace Test.DiffNamespace
{
    class ChangeImage
    {
        Test.MainWindow.imageToChange.Source="images\02.png";  //This doesn't work
    }
}
```

To state the obvious, MainWindow is under Test, while ChangeImage is under Test.DiffNamespace.  I'd ideally like this to work without having to change the structure, but if what I'm attempting isn't possible I'm still open to workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for you assuming you want to update it statically

your class, with a static property pointing to the image

```
class ChangeImage
{
    static ChangeImage()
    {
        Image = "images\02.png";
    }

    public static string Image { get; set; }
}
```

XAML, notice added namespace 'diff' and the image source binding

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:diff="clr-namespace:Test.DiffNamespace">
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="imageToChange" 
           Source="{Binding Source={x:Static diff:ChangeImage.Image}}" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
           Height="100" 
           VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           Width="100" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If image is embedded as a resource you should use following code

```
class ChangeImage
{
     // Test.MainWindow.imageToChange.Source="images\02.png";  //This doesn't work
    BitmapImage logo = new BitmapImage();
    logo.BeginInit();
    logo.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Resources/logo.png");
    logo.EndInit();
    Test.MainWindow.imageToChange.Source = logo;
}
```

Comment: Please note that BitmapImage has a constuctor that takes an `Uri` argument. Using that eliminates the need for calling BeginInit and EndInit. You may simply write `Test.MainWindow.imageToChange.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(...));`.

Comment: And there is a short form of the Pack URI for resources in the same assembly: `pack://application:,,,/Subfolder/ResourceFile`. So in short: `Test.MainWindow.imageToChange.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/02.png"));`.